# How do select the active element in my code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a reusable function that I can invoke on the first and last button in button groups to change the innerHTML of the center button. The button groups look like this: |-|0 bedrooms|+|. I'm having trouble selecting the active element i.e. the "-" or "+" button so I can traverse to the span in the center button which has the innerHTML I want to change.

When I use an element.id as the base of my query, it works and I'm able to access the span element I want, but when I try to use the active element as the base it fails. I need it to be relational and not specific since I will be using the function on different elements.

Here is my javascript:

```
function incDec(i) {
  var thisElem = document.activeElement;
  var getNum = $(thisElem)
      .parent()
      .parent()
      .children(".disabled")
      .children("span")
      .html();
  var count = Number(getNum);
  if (i.value == "4") {
    count -= 1;
    getNum = count;
    $(thisElem)
      .parent()
      .parent()
      .children(".disabled")
      .children("span")
      .empty()
      .append(count);
  } else if (i.value == "5") {
    count += 1;
    getNum = count;
    $(thisElem)
      .parent()
      .parent()
      .children(".disabled")
      .children("span")
      .empty()
      .append(count);
  } else {
  }

}
```

Here is the html:

```
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle pr-4 pt-3 pb-3" data- 
    toggle="buttons">

        <label for="minButton1" class="btn btn-outline-info plus-minus minus">
            <input class="test" type="radio" name="options" id="minButton1" 
            value="4" onclick="incDec(this)"> -
        </label>

        <label class="btn btn-outline-info info-sect disabled">
            <input type="radio" name="bedrooms" id="bedrooms" 
            autocomplete="off">

                <span class="num" id="beds">0</span> Bedrooms
        </label>

        <label for="plusButton1" class="btn btn-outline-info plus-minus plus">

            <input class="test" type="radio" id="plusButton1" 
            name="formselector" value="5" onclick="incDec(this)"> +
        </label>

    </div>
```

Comment: Isn't `i` the active element? It's the button they clicked on.

Comment: What browser are you using? Firefox on macOs has a strange bug with <input> and `document.activeElement`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55929696/why-does-document-activeelement-produce-a-different-result-on-mac-using-firefox/55931283#55931283 Otherwise, your code seems to work for me on Chrome. However, @Barmar is right, you don't even need `document.activeElement` here, `i` should already be the activeElement (in non buggy browsers...)

Comment: @Barmar Yes, of course! That worked. I don't know why I didn't do that. I'm a new user, how do I accept your answer? I can't see any icons or checkboxes anywhere. All I see is a report flag next to your comment

Comment: @MichaelTaylor We didn't post an answer, it's too trivial to bother.

Comment: @MichaelTaylor are you using this browser? (Firefox on macOs?)

Comment: @Kaiido Chrome Version 74.0.3729.131 (Official Build) (64-bit) on Windows 10

Comment: Ah interesting then, your code should have worked there...

Comment: It was in a codepen. Maybe that had something to do with it.